# View doesn't aligned in the center of layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple layout, as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text: "NOT CENTRALIZED!" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />   
</RelativeLayout>
```

The above layout belongs to a Fragment which is loaded inside a ViewPager (which belongs to an Activity - called here as ActivityA.java).

The ActivityA.java xml layout file is like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/elevated_appbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Note that I'm using the **CoordinatorLayout** and my **ViewPager** has the 
`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` attribute.

The little thing that makes me confusing is: Why my TextView is not centralized on the layout since I'm declaring `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` and `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to it?!

Strangely, when I remove the `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` attribute on **android.support.v4.view.ViewPager** the content is displayed on the middle of the screen, but... the **android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar** stops the collapse and expand features.

[image: Demonstrating the issue - image 1]

**EDIT**

On the layout preview, we can see that the `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` is not above the navigation bar (but the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` is needed to put this view bellow the `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`). When removing this attribute, the `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` goes up the navigation bar, but overlaps the `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`.

Take a look:

With `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`:

[image: Demonstrating the issue - image 2]

Without `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`:

[image: Demonstrating the issue - image 3]

**EDIT 2**

So, I decided to do a test to reproduce this issue on a [well referenced project](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) which demonstrates some Material features and the result is...

[image: Demonstrating the issue - cheesesquare project]

... the same problem!

If someone wants to reproduce it yourself, only change the [fragment_cheese_list.xml](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_cheese_list.xml) to:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/alertMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="ALSO, NOT CENTRALIZED..." />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe because you are using too many things in one layout !

Comment: user android:layout_centerInParent="true" for your textview

Comment: As I said, app:layout_behavior attribute is need to expand and collapse the toolbar. Removing it all looks good (the TextView is on the middle of the layout). Maybe I forgot to post that the fragment contains a recyclerView too (a list of items to scroll up and down which reproduces the collapsing and expanding effect).

Comment: Well, the android:layout_centerInParent="true" doesn't work. If I remove all atributes to center my textView it goes to the top left of the layout as expected, but, only when trying to put it on the center of the layout this strange thing happens. Looks like app:layout_behavior changes the margin when we need to add a view to the center of layout...

Comment: Here is a similar question with a suggested simple solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47479847/5536197

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your Fragment's layout xml file.

**Edit1**

Actually it is behaving as it is supposed to.
When you have your `Viewpager` with:`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Android shifts your `ViewPager` down, according to the height of `AppBarLayout` (Might be adding margin to it). And this margin is readjusted when you scroll your view up. Because that is what `scrolling_view_behavior` is

[image]

And without:`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Your `ViewPager` is independent of `AppBarLAyout` Hence, no margin thats why your `TextView` Appears in center in this case.
[image]

So, in reality, your TextView is always in center of your ViewPager. Its the ViewPager that shifts. For changing that behavior you might need to implement your own Layout Behavior. [This](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.java#1319) is how android does it.

Comment: Doesn't work! See the last edit above (it shows what is happening with the preview helper).

Comment: in same preview helper, with: `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`, can you check position of your text view, in RelativeLayout. Can you post that preview?

Comment: Also doesn't work! The position is the same as the previous without this attribute. See my edit 2, it demonstrates the same issue on [cheesesquare project](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @n.arrow001! But I really would appreciate your answer if you demonstrate how to handle this issue using a custom layout behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and not-obtrusive workaround I've found is to set a bottom padding to your container on onOffsetChanged. This will look like

```
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            container.setPadding(0, 0, 0, appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange() + verticalOffset);
        ...
```